# "Resource temporarily unavailable (os error 11)" Transport error when using thrift rpc（rust）

Tags: java, rust, rpc, transport

I defined a service like:

```
service xxService {
  ResultA funcA(),
  ResultB funcB()
}
```

in a `demo.thrift` file, then I used `thrift --gen rust demo.thrift`, got a file named `demo.rs`, with `funA()` and `funcB()` defined in it.

The rpc server is written in `java`, and the client is written in `rust`.

When I called `funcA()` repeatedly and constantly to get some info from my rpc server, in the beginning everything went well, but after a few minutes, I got a `transport error` when calling `funcA()`, the call procedure is like this:

from

```rust
fn funcA() -> ResultA {
  // other code
  let message_ident = self.i_prot_mut().read_message_begin()?;
  // other code
}
```

to

```rust
#[allow(clippy::collapsible_if)]
fn read_message_begin(&mut self) -> crate::Result<TMessageIdentifier> {
  let mut first_bytes = vec![0; 4];
  self.transport.read_exact(&mut first_bytes[..])?;
  // other code
}
```

I found in debug mode that this error occured in the `read_exact()` method in function `read_message_begin()`.This is the file of thrift named `binary.rs`.

The error look like this:

```
TransportError { kind: Unknown, message: "Resource temporarily unavailable (os error 11)" }
```

But I have no idea why it occured, the rpc client process and server process both look good.

Ignoring this error will receive same error in the next loop.